# Why is an integer literal followed by a dot a valid numeric literal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, literals

In JavaScript it is valid to end an integer numeric literal with a dot, like so...

```
x = 5.;
```

What's the point of having this notation? Is there any reason to put the dot at the end, and if not, why is that notation allowed in the first place?

**Update:** Ok guys, since you mention floats and integers... We are talking about JavaScript here. There is only one number type in JavaScript which is IEEE-754.

`5` and `5.` have the same value, there is no difference between those two values.

Comment: What's more interesting to me is that javascript allows `05` and `5.` but not `05.`.

Comment: Thats because the `0` prefix makes it an octal number, how would you express an octal float? ;)

Comment: @Ivo - Ah, indeed it does. `09.` does work. Thanks! :o)

Comment: @Ivo the same way you express a decimal or binary float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You DO need the decimal point if you call a **method** on an integer:

```
5.toFixed(n) // throws an error

5..toFixed(n) // returns the string '5.' followed by n zeroes
```

If that doesn't look right, `(5).toFixed(n)`, or `5.0.toFixed(n)`, will work, too.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is just compatibility with other C-like languages where the dot does matter.

Comment: I'd call that legacy... But yes, that's probably the reason. I guess, the creator of JavaScript just copied the notation from C, but then later decided to define only one number type (and then didn't think of revisiting the notation).

Answer (score 1):

That's a floating point number. Unlike any other language I've ever encountered, *all* numbers in Javascript are actually 64-bit floating numbers. Technically, there are no native integers in Javascript. See [The Complete Javascript Number Reference](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference) for the full ugly story.

Comment: Sure (sorry I hadn't noticed earlier):


* I don't think you are answering OP's question (i.e. about parsing and notations, not number size)
* Javascript's numbers are considered reliable up to a bound, which means that you don't need to treat them as usual floating-points (i.e. you can do 10.0/2 == 5, which you shouldn't with normal floating points)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer in this case is, that it makes absolutely no difference.

Every number in JavaScript is already a 64bit floating point number.

The "`. syntax`" is only useful in cases where you can ommit the fixed part because it's `0`:

```
.2 // Will end up as 0.2
-.5 // Will end up as -0.5
```

So overall it's just saving a byte, but it makes the code less readable at the same time.

Comment: It would make sense that non-integer values (values with decimal fractions) have the dot (obviously) and integer values don't. so either it is just an integer like 5 or it is a real number like 5.01 ... but why is 5. allowed? If the dot in this case does not make a difference then this notation is useless. Why whould they enable this notation then?

Answer (score -1):

What if it wouldn't be an integer, but a floating point literal?